# Calling a view controller from index.html

Tags: angularjs

I have an index.html that has a top bar with links and a side bar with links. I want the center to be replaced with content (ng-view). Let's say the top bar is Pictures, Stats, Chat. The side bar is Tigers, Lions, Bears.

These never change. This is why index.html holds them. The top bar of Pictures, Stats, Chat I want to actually route to different views/controllers (replaces ng-view on index.html). Easy.

However, when inside a given view controller (let's say Pictures) I now want to know what side bar was clicked (I would like to default to a given side bar animal when Pictures is first clicked in the app since that would be required) and I'd also like to be able to copy the link directly to there (ie Pictures/Bears (but this always just goes to the Pictures controller but inside there I know Bears was clicked so I can act accordingly)).

So if I click Tigers, the controller will know this and I can code it to get pictures of Tigers.

I don't want to put that side bar into each page itself since it's always the same. I just want it on index.html to avoid repeating myself even though this would be more direct in terms of coding each top bar view. This would be something I'd fall back to in the case of what I'm asking to do isn't possible.

I'm also wondering if it's possible to maintain the current side bar value when they click on a different top link animal. So if I was in Pictures/Lions and they click Bears, it would know to route Pictures/Bears. Since it's staying in Pictures would it really even need to route? Can it route and then call a method on the Pictures controller passing in the animal so it can do what it needs to with that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a service like `animalService` that keeps track of the selected animal.  This will act like your own route handler for just that side menu.

The controller for the side menu would then be able to call `animalService.selectAnimal(selectedAnimal)` to update the selection.

Each main page controller could then watch the value of the selected animal from `animalService`.  There are a few ways to do this, but it would probably be easiest to use a subscription based approach:

Each controller would call `animalService.subscribeToChange('controllerName', callback)` on initialization and then on destroy it would call `animalService.unsubscribeFromChange('controllerName')`.  The `animalService` would keep a list/map of all of the subscribed controllers, so it can execute the callback every time the `selectAnimal` function is called and detects a change.

If you provide a code sample I could try to give a more detailed solution.

#### Alternatively

You could take advantage of `$rootScope`.  I find this a bit more hacky, but it would be probably quicker to implement.  The side menu can access a root scope variable via something like `$root.currentAnimal`, and it can both get and set that value.  Then each controller can use `$rootScope.$watch('currentAnimal', function() {})` to trigger something on change (`$rootScope` is a service).

Comment: Interesting idea. This way wouldn't give any sort of direct url routing I assume? By that I mean I couldn't send Pictures/Lions link to a user and have it go directly to that right?

Comment: That part would be up to you.  You could use $routeParams that the animalService reads to set the default animal.  i.e. `#/pictures?animal=Lions`